# Solaris 11 pkginfo vs pkg info

Tags: solaris

What is the difference between `pkginfo` and `pkg info` (on Solaris 11)? Why `pkginfo` does not list packages such as `developer/gcc-45`, `system/header` and `pkg info` does not list packages from OpenCSW? Is there a unified way to show info about all the packages installed in the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pkginfo` is for SVR4 legacy packages while `pkg info` is for IPS packages.

Some IPS packages do provide a SVR4 equivalence but you can't have a SVR4 package providing IPS information.

I'm afraid you have to consolidate both output yourself.